# Is it possible to "pipe" audio into the "line in" for a particular program?

Tags: linux, audio

I want to take the audio output of a program, and "pipe" it into the audio input of another program. So I could, say, play a song with Banshee, and have Skype hear it, playing it to whomever is in the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there's a way to solve this problem in a very general way, but in any case I've implemented what I wanted for Skype. You can see it [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/jordyd/Skype-Audio-Shovel). It allows you to select an audio file and play it into an already active Skype call.

Answer (score 5):

For Linux, [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) sounds like what you want to do. It's rather confusing, though. The last time I needed to do something like this I gave up on JACK and just set the (system) audio input to the monitor of the output in PulseAudio (Kubuntu).

For anyone wanting to do this on Windows, [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) does the same thing - and is much more intuitive to use, though that could be my lack of experience with Linux.

Of course, programs like Skype may have their own internal system for doing such a thing and that would be the best to use.

Comment: It looks like I can only use JACK with JACK-aware applications? So, I would have to write a plug-in or something for Skype specifically, if I'm right. That's not a big deal, but at that point for my specific case I could simply read an audio file and play it into the conversation (assuming the Skype API has that functionality, and assuming that there is a Skype API at all), so I wouldn't even need JACK at that point.

Comment: Actually, I'm not going to commit to the uselessness of JACK yet, I'm asking some JACK people right now and will get back to this question soon on the results.

Comment: Ok, so using JACK requires that the application also use JACK, which I don't believe Skype does. I'll have to use the Skype API for this.

Answer (score 2):

For linux, I think you'd want to try Jack, but there's a program that does what you want called [Soundflower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/).

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't really sound possible unless Skype has a built in option for that.  The piping I think your referring to used in IPC (inter-process communication) can only copy data to another process if that other process is expecting to receive it. You're best option is placing the speaker next to the microphone, or searching for some sort of plug-in that can do this.

http://howtoskype.net/how-to-play-audio-music-mp3-files-on-skype/ here's the answer I think you're looking for. :-) They have a plug-in that will allow you to do this, and the basic version is free.